# GMail email import

Tags: gmail

I would like to move all of my ARCHIVE incoming and outgoing mails to GMail. I have admin rights on the server, where all my emails are stored, so I may set up Imap (current case), POP3 or even I write an app, if necessary. If it is possible, I would like to preserve also folder sturcture (of course, as labels). Is there any way to solve this problem?

ThX,
Fx

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: You can use a third party software such as Thunderbird to fetch all the emails and then simply drag and drop into the Gmail account also connected to the same Thunderbird client. I have found that Thunderbird seems to preserve file structure and labels, and auto creates more if they don't exist.

Worth a shot!